# Jenkins job hangs forever referencing variable that hasn't been set

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm trying to construct a convenient shared library for my scripted pipelines.

I want to be able to use an object from my Jenkinsfile that has several functional methods, but also stores some initial variables that are referenced by several methods.

So, I've defined a file in "vars" with a bunch of methods for functionality, but also a handful of get/set methods for the properties I want to store in the object for reference by several methods.

My initial testing is just to set some of the variables (not all of them) and call the "toString()" method which I've defined in the file (just for convention, obviously).

In my test Jenkinsfile, If I do set all of the variables and then call "toString()", it works fine and completes.

However, if I try commenting out one of the variable initializations, when it hits the line in the "toString" method that constructs the return value, Jenkins just hangs forever.  I eventually just kill the job.

I've been able to avoid the hang by qualifying each reference with '`if binding.variables.containsKey("foo")) {`', only referencing the variable if that is true.  I made this a tiny bit cleaner by putting the binding check in each of the getter methods instead.

I don't really like this workaround.  It just seems odd that I would have to do this.

I've tried several variations, but I don't set the variable and I try to reference it in a gstring, the job hangs forever, every time.

This is a brief excerpt from the "vars" file:

```
def setJobName(value) { jobName = value; }
//def getJobName() { return jobName }
def getJobName() { return (binding.variables.containsKey("jobName") ? jobName : "") }
def setMechIdCredentials(value) { mechIdCredentials = value; }
//def getMechIdCredentials() { return mechIdCredentials }
def getMechIdCredentials() { return (binding.variables.containsKey("mechIdCredentials") ? mechIdCredentials : "") }
... more get/set methods

String toString() {
    echo "Inside uslutils.toString()."
```

This is an excerpt from the Jenkinsfile that uses this:

```
    uslutils.currentBuild   = currentBuild
    uslutils.jobName        = env.JOB_NAME
    uslutils.buildURL       = env.BUILD_URL
    //uslutils.mechIdCredentials = "abc"

    return "[currentBuild[${currentBuild}] mechIdCredentials[${mechIdCredentials}] " +
           "baseStashURL[${baseStashURL}] jobName[${jobName}] codeBranch[${codeBranch}] " +
           "codeURL[${codeURL}] buildURL[${buildURL}] pullRequestURL[${pullRequestURL}] QBotUserID[${QBotUserID}] " +
           "QBotPassword[${QBotPassword}]]"
}
```

So, for instance, if I swapped the two variations of "getMechIdCredentials", leaving the "plain" one, this combination of samples will hang, until I click on the red X on the "Progress" indicator in Jenkins.

**Update**:

So, based on feedback, I defined variables in the file and changed my getters/setters to use the "this.@var" syntax.  As a result, the build fails with "No such field: var for class: uslutils".

I imagine my syntax for defining the field isn't correct, but here's an excerpt of what I have:

```
def     currentBuild        = ""
String  jobName             = ""
String  buildURL            = ""
def     mechIdCredentials   = ""

def setCurrentBuild(value) { this.@currentBuild = value; }
def getCurrentBuild() { return this.@currentBuild }

def setJobName(value) { this.@jobName   = value; }
def getJobName() { return this.@jobName }

def setBuildURL(value) { this.@buildURL = value; }
def getBuildURL() { return this.@buildURL }

def setMechIdCredentials(value) { this.@mechIdCredentials = value; }
def getMechIdCredentials() { return this.@mechIdCredentials }
```

Note that this is NOT within a "class" declaration, it's in a Groovy script file called "uslutils.groovy".

To be clear, here is an excerpt of the stack trace I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingFieldException: No such field: mechIdCredentials for class: uslutils
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getAttribute(MetaClassImpl.java:2823)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.getAttribute(MetaClassImpl.java:3759)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper.getAttribute(InvokerHelper.java:145)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.getField(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:306)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.sandbox.DefaultInvoker.getAttribute(DefaultInvoker.java:42)
at com.cloudbees.groovy.cps.impl.AttributeAccessBlock.rawGet(AttributeAccessBlock.java:20)
at uslutils.getMechIdCredentials(/opt/app/jenkins/sdt-usl/data/jobs/uslutils-tests/builds/33/libs/usl-pipeline-library/vars/uslutils.groovy:197)
at uslutils.toString(/opt/app/jenkins/sdt-usl/data/jobs/uslutils-tests/builds/33/libs/usl-pipeline-library/vars/uslutils.groovy:242)
at WorkflowScript.run(WorkflowScript:13)
```

Line 242 is shown here:

```
String toString() {
  echo "Inside uslutils.toString()x."
  return "[currentBuild[${currentBuild}] mechIdCredentials[${mechIdCredentials}] " + // line 242
         "baseStashURL[${baseStashURL}] jobName[${jobName}] codeBranch[${codeBranch}] " +
         "codeURL[${codeURL}] buildURL[${buildURL}] pullRequestURL[${pullRequestURL}] QBotUserID[${QBotUserID}] " +
         "QBotPassword[${QBotPassword}]]"
```

}

Comment: Quick drive-by comment: I'm fairly sure this is a known issue; check the Jenkins bug tracker.

Comment: I just looked, searching for "text ~ "pipeline" and text ~ "hang" and (project != 'HOSTING') and status != 'resolved'". I didn't see anything that matches this (except for the one that I filed for this).  There were a couple of cases where the reporter defined a variable with the same name as the property derived from a setter name, but that's not my situation here.

Comment: AFAICT, that's pretty much what you're doing. This looks like https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-31484 — when to `toString()` method tries to resolve `${mechIdCredentials}`, that causes `getMechIdCredentials()` to be called, which tries to `return mechIdCredentials`, which does not exist as a variable, so Groovy attempts to use the `getMechIdCredentials()` accessor method — i.e. it goes into an infinite loop. You'll see this if you add an `echo` to one of your getters before the `return`.

Comment: Ah. Ok. Looks very promising.

Comment: Does that mean that the "vars/acme.groovy" example at https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/ is defective?

Comment: If you don't call `setName()`, then yes. I think in the second example, it's not actually necessary to explicitly define a `class` either. I'll file an issue / poke some other documentation people.